# Coverage test for create view class and update view class

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-views, coverage.py

I'm writing coverage test cases for my app views. I have used Createview and Updateview classes with modelform and also used `get_success_url()` for response redirect.

When I passed data for the form using `self.client.post('/product/add/', data)`, the response was TemplateResponse and status_code was 200, but `get_success_url()` statements were not covered by the test case. So how can I fill and submit the form from TemplateResponse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client is not redirecting to the success url, the data is probably invalid. You can access the form through the response's context, and check the errors:

```
print response.context['form'].errors
```

Comment: Thanks for ur fast response.